# Savefile dialog saving blank file

Tags: vb.net

Can somebody help me fix this code ? The problem is it save blank file.

```
Dim OFD As New OpenFileDialog
        Try
            OFD.Filter = "Binary files (*.bin)|*.bin"
        Finally
        End Try
        If OFD.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

            Dim b() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(OFD.FileName)
            If (b.Count And 1) = 1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("File is not an even number of bytes, so is not filled with 16-bit values")
            Else
                For i As Integer = 0 To b.Count - 2 Step 2
                    b(i) = b(i) Xor b(i + 1)        'these three lines efficiently swap two bytes in place
                    b(i + 1) = b(i) Xor b(i + 1)    
                    b(i) = b(i) Xor b(i + 1)        
                Next
                **Dim SFD As New SaveFileDialog()

                Try
                    SFD.Filter = "Binary files (*.bin)|*.bin"
                Finally
                End Try
                If SFD.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then**



                End If
            End If
            End If
    End Sub
```

It should save modified binary file:
But it saves blank file. Without any offset

Comment: Um, no. You have to write the file yourself. `SaveFileDialog` only lets the user select a filename; you still have to write the file contents out to a file with that name yourself.

Comment: Need example in code

Comment: Need you to do own work. See `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes` and the documentation for `SaveFileDialog` (both available at MSDN). Once you've done that, tried to use it, and it doesn't work for you, you can post the code that you've tried, explain the problem you're having, and ask a question about that code.

Comment: If you haven't figured it out yet, @KenWhite basically gave you the answer: You just need to add this one line inside your last If statement: `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(SFD.FileName, b)`

Comment: @Joey: Nice job killing the teaching opportunity (which is exactly why I didn't post an answer). I wrote "Here's a hint to get you started, so you can learn in the process", and then you threw it away by adding "In case you can't be bothered to do the work to learn, here's the answer".

Comment: @KenWhite while I agree with you to an extent it reminds me of a blog post I read by Michael Richer about why he will no longer contribute to SO: http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow. Basically he gives the analogy of giving a man a fish and teaching a man to fish and his position is that SO is full of people giving answers and nobody teaching. But as a number of people mentioned in the comments, sometimes all they need is a fish and they can continue with their work. This guy has obviously done the rest of the work, he was just missing one line.

Comment: @Joey: No, handing out a fish just leads to the person following you around waiting for another fish handout. No problem; as you've wasted the opportunity already, I went ahead and wrote an answer. Opportunity lost.

Comment: the relevant portions of **SaveFileDialog** is **Dialog** not SaveFile.  The dialog has no idea what format you want it saved it, nor **what** you want saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A call to `SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog` does not automatically create the file. It simply allows the user to provide a filename that your code then uses to actually save the file contents.

You need to use `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes` after the user provides the filename. You can retrieve the name they provided from the `SaveFileDialog.FileName`. Here's an example:

```
If SFD.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
  System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(SFD.FileName, b)
End If
```